# Android crazy speed and distance traveled

Tags: android, location, distance

I've created simple program for calculating my position and wanted to calculate the speed and overall distance traveled by the user when the app is on.
The Location seems to be working well but when I am trying to calculate speed and distance it shows me some crazy numbers while my phone is not moving, connected to the computer. What's wrong there?

Here is my code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LocationManager locationManager;
TextView tvSpeed;
TextView tvLong;
TextView tvLati;
TextView tvDistance;
double oldLat;
double oldLong;
double startTime;
double endTime;
double overalDistance;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    tvSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSpeed);
    tvLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLong);
    tvLati = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLati);
    tvDistance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDistance);

    oldLat = 0;
    oldLong = 0;
    overalDistance = 0;
    startTime= SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();



    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        return;
    }
    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                endTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                tvLati.setText("Latitude: " + Double.toString(latitude));
                tvLati.invalidate();
                tvLong.setText("Longitude: " + Double.toString(longitude));
                tvLong.invalidate();
                double distance = getDistance(oldLat,oldLong,latitude,longitude);
                double time = (endTime - startTime)/1000;
                startTime=endTime;
                oldLat = latitude;
                oldLong = longitude;
                tvSpeed.setText("Speed: " + Double.toString(distance/time));
                tvSpeed.invalidate();
                overalDistance += distance;
                tvDistance.setText("Overall Distance: " + Double.toString(overalDistance));
                tvDistance.invalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        });
    }
    else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                endTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                tvLati.setText("Latitude: " + Double.toString(latitude));
                tvLati.invalidate();
                tvLong.setText("Longitude: " + Double.toString(longitude));
                tvLong.invalidate();
                double distance = getDistance(oldLat,oldLong,latitude,longitude);
                double time = (endTime - startTime)/1000;
                startTime=endTime;
                oldLat = latitude;
                oldLong = longitude;
                tvSpeed.setText("Speed: " + Double.toString(distance/time));
                tvSpeed.invalidate();
                overalDistance += distance;
                tvDistance.setText("Overall Distance: " + Double.toString(overalDistance));
                tvDistance.invalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        });

    }
}

public double getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
{
    double latA = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    double lonA = Math.toRadians(lon1);
    double latB = Math.toRadians(lat2);
    double lonB = Math.toRadians(lon2);
    double cosAng = (Math.cos(latA) * Math.cos(latB) * Math.cos(lonB-lonA)) +
            (Math.sin(latA) * Math.sin(latB));
    double ang = Math.acos(cosAng);
    double dist = ang *6371;
    return dist;
}
```

and here is the output on my phone
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SLT9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize your `oldLat` and `oldLong` variables to 0. So, the first time that your application have a location, it calculates distance between your current position and (0,0) coordinates.

You must implement an if statement to not calculate distance the first time :

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    tvLati.setText("Latitude: " + Double.toString(latitude));
    tvLati.invalidate();
    tvLong.setText("Longitude: " + Double.toString(longitude));
    tvLong.invalidate();

    if(oldLat == 0 && oldLong == 0) {
         oldLat = latitude;
         oldLong = longitude;
         return;
    }

    endTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    double distance = getDistance(oldLat,oldLong,latitude,longitude);
    double time = (endTime - startTime)/1000;
    startTime=endTime;
    oldLat = latitude;
    oldLong = longitude;
    tvSpeed.setText("Speed: " + Double.toString(distance/time));
    tvSpeed.invalidate();
    overalDistance += distance;
    tvDistance.setText("Overall Distance: " + Double.toString(overalDistance));
    tvDistance.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It was so obvious. But now as I am testing this it's pretty 
inaccurate. Is it because of I am using android.location.* and I should google.gms.location? It seems like if i want to change this I have to rewrite whole project.

Comment: I use android.location.* for my projects and it's pretty stable. But maybe don't use network provider, it is more inaccurate than GPS provider (but it takes time to find location).
By the way, if my answer corrects your problem, thank to accept it.

Comment: I've added TextView to show me time between two times my program enters "onLocationChange" and while I was driving a car the time was between 19 and 22 seconds. That makes localization pretty inaccurate.
GPS provider is more accurate than Network?